# Show custom Credit/Debit card form on Payment Page

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal-express, credit-card

I am working on a project magento 2.2 and client to show only Credit/Debit card form (backend connected with paypal, means we can use Paypal Express Checkout)

But client want not to show list or event Paypal Express Checkout as a payment method but client want to show that Popup occur on that page. (having option to log-in with paypal or pay with debit/credit card)

I have tried custom payment extension by webkul but it didn't work.

One more way I have in my mind, that what if I show that Paypal popup in an iframe instead of list of payments.

Will it workable ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pay with paypal via card then its in build functionality in magento

Enable "Enable PayPal Guest Checkout" in Magento2 Admin and also in paypal.

Now you can redirect to paypal and below login you can see option to pay with card

https://prnt.sc/13g1l7m